# Javascript window resize when changed by user

Tags: javascript, html

The function below isn't working where am I going wrong, any advice very much appreciated...

```
window.onresize = function() { 
    'use strict'; 
    if (window.innerHeight <= 768){ 
        window.resizeTo(768); 
    }
    if (window.innerWidth <= 1024){  
        window.resizeTo(1024); 
    }
}
```

Comment: You're missing a `}`.

Comment: BTW, you don't need to put `;` after the `}` that ends a block.

Comment: The semi colons at the end of the `if` statements are not needed

Comment: I'm new to javascript (sorry if its obvious) where should the } appear, other than that am I right in saying this should work! Thank you for your help...

Comment: Why are you using `use strict` twice there? You can set it once on top!

Answer (score 0):

The method window.resizeTo(width, height) needs two parameters: width and height.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a function to an onresize event, this will result in a loop because calling resize from within the onresize event will trigger another call and so on ....

See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_resizeto.asp

For information on how to resize the window.